# How to solve conflict between two models, one in template and other in a View in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am having problems when I have a `model` in my navigation partial and a model in my registration view (which of course is in `@RenderBody()`

This is the error I am getting

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'ProfessionalDev.Models.Registration', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'ProfessionalDev.Models.Login'.
Line 14: <body>
Line 15: 
Line 16:     @Html.Partial("_Navigation") <=== THE ERROR IS HERE
Line 17:     <div class="top-bg"></div>
Line 18:     <div class="container body-content">
```

My layout if as follows

```
@Html.Partial("_Navigation")
<div class="top-bg"></div>
<div class="container body-content">
    @Html.Partial("_Header")
    <main>
        @RenderBody()
    </main>
    <footer>
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2009-@DateTime.Now.Year  Company</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

The `_Navigation` partial where I have a `Login` model because of the Login form

```
@model ProfessionalDev.Models.Login

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            ...

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            @Html.Partial("_Messages")

                            @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) {
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Email" })

                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Passwd)
                                @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Passwd, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Password" })

                                <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="action:Login" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" />
                            }
                        </li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></li>
                    </ul>
            ...
```

Then I have the Registration view with a `Registration` model

```
@model ProfessionalDev.Models.Registration

@{ 
    ProfessionalDev.Library.IdentifierTypeItems identifierTypes = new ProfessionalDev.Library.IdentifierTypeItems();
}
<h1>New User Account</h1>
<hr />

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Registration", FormMethod.Post)) {
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, "First Name", new { @class = "control-label" }) <span class="required">* </span>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            ...
    <input type="submit" value="Register" name="action:Register" class="btn btn-primary" />
}
```

RegistrationController

```
public class RegistrationController : Controller
{
    // GET: Registration
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [MultipleButton(Name = "action", Argument = "Register")]
    public ActionResult Index(Registration reg) {

        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            ...
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        return View("Index", reg);
    }
}
```

When I click the Register button and the `Registration` object is invalid, as you can see above is supposed to return `reg` to the `Registration/Index` view, but instead is returning the view to the `Home/Index` view from the `_Navigation` partial

HomeController

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [MultipleButton(Name = "action", Argument = "Login")]
    public ActionResult Index(Login login)
    {
       ...
        return View("Index", login);
    }
```

(I hope I am making sense...)

How can I fix this?

This is how it looks from GUI. The Login in the top menu and the register page

[image]

Comment: The error is self explanatory. Your not passing and instance of `Login` to the partial - use `@Html.Partial("_Navigation", new Login())` - by default if you do not specify a model, it will use the model form the main view.

Comment: I followed your approach, but instead I created a variable for login `ProfessionalDev.Models.Login login = new ProfessionalDev.Models.Login();
` then passed it to the navigation partial `@Html.Partial("_Navigation", login)`. This was works except that when I submit the registration form, the login object also returns with errors https://goo.gl/khA67u I understand the concept and why this is happening, I just need to figure out a way to handle this

Answer (score 0):

You get redirected to because you using `@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))` inside your main view and doesn't matter what is inside your partial view. 
Besides, Only way you could call partial view method inside a main view is jQuery.

The best approach is using a `ProfessionalDev.Models.Login` type property inside your `ProfessionalDev.Models.Registration`.

Then use your `Html.BeginForm` for login inside the registration view.